# Symfony 4 addFlash appears on network tab but not on the page

Tags: php, symfony, controller, twig

The strange thing I've got here. I've copied everything from S4 Doc's, however it does not seem working as intended.
Controller code:

```
// Adding a success type message
$this->addFlash("success", "This is a success message");
// Adding a warning type message
$this->addFlash("warning", "This is a warning message");
// Adding an error type message
$this->addFlash("error", "This is an error message");
// Adding a custom type message, remember the type is totally up to you !
$this->addFlash("bat-alarm", "Gotham needs Batman");
// 2. Retrieve manually the flashbag
// Retrieve flashbag from the controller
$flashbag = $this->get('session')->getFlashBag();
// Set a flash message
$flashbag->add("other", "This is another flash message with other type");
// Render some twig view
$carList = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(CarProject::class)->findAll();                
return $this->render('index.html.twig', array ('carList' => $carList));
```

index.html.twig code:

```
<div>
      {% for flash_message in app.session.flashBag.get('success') %}
        <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ flash_message }}
   </div>
      {% endfor %}
   </div>
```

I can see that it is loaded on Chrome DevTools Network tab being the latest response on the list, however it does not appear on the actual page.
[image]
Any ideas?

Comment: You are only fetching "success" messages, while setting many other types of messages in your controller. 
Could you insert a `{{ dump(app.flashes) }}` ?

Comment: It does not make any difference here, as the page does not reload this is why flash messages does not appear. I need somehow to flash without page being reloaded.

Comment: It looks like your are expecting an AJAX flash message. Like this ? https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/

Comment: For ajax you're out of luck with Twig-only, it's more complex. Totally possible but you're looking at the wrong place for this, it's Javascript + Ajax tutorial you should be looking for.

Comment: Yes indeed I've done that with ajax. That flash method was quite appealing and thought it will work, new on S4 tho. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Definitive answer from my comment so that you can resolve this question: you are trying to do AJAX flashes which aren't possible in pure twig.

You should either look up for something like [toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) or play around with some jquery plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You want a Symfony 4 flash that really works? (This does not mean that the doc doesn't work)

An action of your controller: (

(**TranslatorInterface** must be imported by: `use Symfony\Component\Translation\TranslatorInterface;`)

```
public function new(Request $request, TranslatorInterface $translator): Response
{

    // If you want to get the message from the translations file
    $this->addFlash(
        'success',
        $translator->trans('user.edit.flash.success', [
            '%user_info%' => 'balzacLeGeek',
        ])
    );

    // If you want to set the message directly
    $this->addFlash(
        'success',
        'L\'utilisateur balzacLeGeek a été mise à jour avec succes'
    );

    // Rest of your code 
    // here ....
}
```

In your Twig view (***base.html.twig***)

```
{% for label, messages in app.flashes %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <div class="alert alert-{{ label }}" role="alert">
          {{ message }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you have used a translation in your controller, this is the translation file what I have for an example: (inside ***translations/translation.en.yaml***)

```
user:
    edit:
        flash:
            success: Great! The user %metier_info% was edited
            error: Sorry! An error was occurend when we have trying to update %metier_info%.
```

---

I case you want to use ***bootstrap-notify***, let's customize something

In your Twig view (***base.html.twig***)

```
{% for label, messages in app.flashes %}
    {% for message in messages %}
        <input type="hidden" class="notifyLabel" value="{{ label }}">
        <input type="hidden" class="notifyMessage" value="{{ message }}">
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Always in the ***base.html.twig*** but in your **scripts** section

```
<script src="https://github.com/mouse0270/bootstrap-notify/releases/download/3.1.3/bootstrap-notify.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        var notifyLabel = $('.notifyLabel').val();
        var notifyMessage = $('.notifyMessage').val();

        if(notifyLabel != undefined) {
            $.notify({
                    // options
                    icon: 'fas fa-check-circle',
                    title: '',
                    message: notifyMessage,
                    url: '',
                    target: '_blank'
                },{
                    // settings
                    element: 'body',
                    type: notifyLabel,
                    allow_dismiss: true,
                    placement: {
                        from: "bottom",
                        align: "right"
                    },
                    animate: {
                        enter: 'animated bounceIn',
                        exit: 'animated bounceOut'
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    });
</script>
```

Last, let's adding some style :-)

```
<style type="text/css">
    .notice {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #fafafa;
        border-left: 6px solid #7f7f84;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px -6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
           -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 8px -6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
                box-shadow: 0 5px 8px -6px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
    }
    .notice-sm {
        padding: 10px;
        font-size: 80%;
    }
    .notice-lg {
        padding: 35px;
        font-size: large;
    }
    .notice-success {
        border-color: #80D651;
    }
    .notice-success>strong {
        color: #80D651;
    }
    .notice-info {
        border-color: #45ABCD;
    }
    .notice-info>strong {
        color: #45ABCD;
    }
    .notice-warning {
        border-color: #FEAF20;
    }
    .notice-warning>strong {
        color: #FEAF20;
    }
    .notice-danger {
        border-color: #d73814;
    }
    .notice-danger>strong {
        color: #d73814;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer, however it still does not work as per your example :/ After your controller code I have to add some return in my case I add render index twig file and the result is very same, I can see on Network tab that it was actually loaded, but does not appear on my page.

Answer (score 0):

The [Symfony docs](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-improved-flash-messages) indicate that you should use `{{ app.flashes }}`. Like this example:

```
    {% for label, messages in app.flashes(['warning', 'error']) %}
        {% for message in messages %}
            <div class="alert alert-{{ label }}">
                {{ message }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi, I've used all the examples on earth possible, still nothing. I think this is because, when I click a button, server gives me correct response, however it does not displays on the page since it requires a page reload? Once I reload the page I get the correct response. But I don't want reload a page on my case, any ideas how to use addFlash and avoid page reload?

Comment: Can you show your index.html.twig codes? and the base.html.twig